# jquery bubblepopup to appear onclick on a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, onclick

So what I'm trying to achieve is a popup that shows itself to the user once they click on the textbox. I'm using the jquery bubblepopup plug-in but I can't seem to assign it to click function. There are 2 functions, one roll over and one click I've seperated them if anything.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#info-header').CreateBubblePopup({
        innerHtml: $('#info-pop').html(),
        themeName: 'all-grey',
        themePath: '../content/themes/jquerybubblepopup-theme',
        position: 'right',
        align: 'middle',
        tail: 'right',
        innerHtmlStyle: {
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            'text-align': 'left'
        }
    });


    $('#Password').click(function(){
        var popup_button = $(this);
        popup_button.CreatebubblePopup({
         themeName: 'all-grey',
            themePath: '../content/themes/jquerybubblepopup-theme',
            position: 'top',
            align: 'top',
            tail: 'bottom',
            width: '250px',

            innerHtml: '<p>Password Requirements</p><ul><li>Must be at least 6 characters</li> <li>Must include at least 3 of the 4 following items:<ul><li>uppercase letters</li><li>lowercase letters</li><li>numbers</li><li>special characters</li></ul></li></ul>',
            innerHtmlStyle: {
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                'text-align': 'left',
                'margin-top': '0'
            }
        });

        popup_button.FreezeBubblePopup();
        $('#Password').click(function(){
            $(popup_button).HideBubblePopup();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So, what's happening instead?

Comment: Why do you have a click handler inside another one?

Comment: Have you tried `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: It doesn't have any syntax errors but the click function isn't working. I wanted to add another click function so it hides bubblepopup afterwards.

Comment: To hide/show you can use `.toggle()`. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found out the solution, I had a small letter for the id. and I switched from button onclick to focus, and used blur to cancel or take out the effect.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#Password').focus(function () {
            var popup_button = $(this);
            popup_button.CreateBubblePopup({
                themeName: 'all-grey',
                themePath: '../content/themes/jquerybubblepopup-theme',
                position: 'top',
                align: 'top',
                tail: 'bottom',
                width: '250px',
                mosueOver: 'hide',
                innerHtml: '<p style="font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;">Password Requirements</p><ul style="margin-left:-25px;"><li>Must be at least 6 characters</li> <li>Must have 3 of the following:<ul style="margin-left:-25px;"><li>uppercase letters</li><li>lowercase letters</li><li>numbers</li><li>special characters</li></ul></li></ul>',
                innerHtmlStyle: {
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    'text-align': 'left',
                    'margin-top': '-10px',
                    'font-size' : '12px',
                    'padding' : '0 10px'
                }
            });
            popup_button.ShowBubblePopup();
            popup_button.FreezeBubblePopup();

            $('#Password').blur(function () {
                popup_button.UnfreezeBubblePopup();
                popup_button.RemoveBubblePopup();
            });


        });

    });
```